# Inserting ErrorT at the base of transformer stack

Tags: haskell, error-handling, monads, monad-transformers

What is the best way to run a code with type `t (ErrorT String IO) a` from within a `t IO a` monad? Consider the code below:

```
module Sample where

import System.IO
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Error

type Env = String

inner :: ReaderT Env (ErrorT String IO) ()
inner = do
    s <- ask
    fail s

outer :: ReaderT Env IO ()
outer = do
    env <- ask
    res <- lift $ runErrorT $ runReaderT inner env
    case res of
        Left err -> liftIO $ hPutStrLn stderr err
        Right _ -> return ()
    outer
```

This works, but I've been looking for a more graceful way of inserting ErrorT at the base of my stack. Especially that I'm using several different monad transformer stacks in my project and writing the above for each of them is quite tedious.

I was looking for something like:

```
outer :: ReaderT Env IO ()
outer = do
    res <- (hoist runErrorT) inner
    ...
```

But I cannot use `hoist` due to type mismatch.

---

Edit:

I use `StateT` in some of my stacks and that's the reason for trying to put `ErrorT` at the base and not on the top.

The `outer` is supposed to be an infinite loop.

Comment: is outer really supposed to be an infinite loop?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam Why not? Haskell is lazy so `runReaderT` will yield a useful `IO` action

Comment: The IO action might well be useful because it interacts with the user on each iteration or similar - it's just that I thought from the question that outer is supposed to be like inner but with the ErrorT String removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that as Edward says, it would generally a lot simpler to put the `ErrorT` at the top of the stack, not the bottom.

This can change the semantics of the stack, at least for more complicated transformers than `ReaderT` - e.g. if you have `StateT` in the stack, then with `ErrorT` at the bottom changes to the state will be rolled back when there's an error, whereas with `ErrorT` at the top, changes to the state will be kept when there's an error.

If you do really need it at the bottom, then something like this passes the type checker:

```
import Control.Monad.Error
import Control.Monad.Morph
import System.IO

toOuter :: MFunctor t => t (ErrorT String IO) a -> t IO a
toOuter = hoist runErrorTWithPrint

runErrorTWithPrint :: ErrorT String IO a -> IO a
runErrorTWithPrint m = do
   res <- runErrorT m
   case res of
       Left err -> do
           hPutStrLn stderr err
           fail err
       Right v -> return v
```

Note that it calls `fail` when the inner computation fails, which isn't what your code above does.

The main reason is that to use `hoist` we need to provide a function of type `forall a . ErrorT String IO a -> IO a` - i.e. to handle any kind of value, not just `()`. This is because the depending on the rest of the monad stack might mean that the actual return type when you get to the `ErrorT` is different to the return type you started with.

In the failure case, we don't have a value of type `a` so one option is to fail.

In your original code you also loop infinitely in `outer`, which this doesn't do.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I should've made it clearer in the question that I want the `outer` to be an infinite loop. I guess my best bet would be to use something like `catchAndIgnoreException $ (hoist runErrorTWithPrint) inner`

Comment: That feels quite ugly, but I guess it would work. The other options I see are: (a) change "fail err" to "return undefined" and hope that nothing in the stack actually inspects the return value. (b) try to write something like MFunctor/hoist yourself, but with a more restricted type and working on a smaller set of monads, so that runErrorTWithPrint doesn't need to be polymorphic. I suspect that StateT will defeat both these options, however.

Comment: I agree, that's terribly ugly. But since the project will be dead after the semester at my university ends, it will do. I've just checked that returning undefined does not work.

Answer (score 5):

The right answer here is "don't do that".

The problem here is you're picking the layering. If you move the `Error` to the outside it'll behave properly for `fail` in this situation. In general view the transformer stack as some kind of quantum waveform you shouldn't collapse until the last minute.

```
inner :: MonadReader Env m => m ()
inner = do
  s <- ask
  fail s

outer :: (MonadReader Env m, MonadIO m) => m ()
outer = do
  res <- runErrorT inner
  case res of
    Left err -> liftIO $ hPutStrLn stderr err
    Right _  -> return ()
  outer
```

Notice how much simpler everything gets. No hoisting, no explicit lifting, nada. `inner` is run in a different monad where we've extended our current monad whatever it is, with ErrorT on the outside.

By not picking the stack explicitly you maximize the number of situations in which you can use the code.

If you absolutely have to do it, then follow Ganesh's path, but think hard about whether you actually need to morph in the situation you described!

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, as I've just written in the question, I use `StateT` in some of my stacks and would rather use `ErrorT` below it, not on top.

Comment: Then you are probably stuck with a solution involving `hoist`.